# How to adjust .navbar and replace 'toggle navigation' text for a dropdown menu?

Tags: css

I can't figure out how to adjust my .navbar in CSS so that instead of the menu text being displayed vertically, they are displayed horizontally across the top of my webpage.

Second, I don't understand why the 'toggle navigation' text is displayed (on mobile and desktop site versions) at the top of my website and isn't instead (just on mobile versions) a dropdown menu that drops down menu text upon a click, or (just on desktop site versions) the 'toggle navigation' text nonexistent and just shows the menu text. How can I get rid of the 'toggle navigation' text on both desktop and mobile site versions but keep the drowndown menu for mobile devices, but with a three lines icon for the dropdown menu.

My website is www.hintdrop.com and you will see what I am referring to once the page loads. The problem area will be at the top of the front page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may set your your main menu's display to inline-flex. You may add the css below

```
#main-menu{
    display: inline-flex;
}
```

For the other question, I would recommend changing the entire logic. What you are asking for is straightforward. You may check this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp). Esspecially, you already use Bootstrap.

Comment: Thank you, this worked great! Do you know how to edit the desktop version of my site separately from the mobile version of my site? I'm wondering because when I change code to make the desktop version look good, the mobile version looks not so great.

Comment: Glad I can help. For the mobile rendering, you may use the media css rule. Based on some maximum and minimum width, you can manage the display of some elements. For instance, in Bootstrap grid system, the columns are displayed vertically when the width is too small, which is the case in mobile devices, You will need to go through you css and add the required rules that make your UI looks better when the width is too small; i.e. @media (max-width: 992px) for instance. You may also hide some elements such as icons or navigation header in order to give more space.